# RDS instance script

Tags: amazon-rds

Can anyone help me how should a bash script to check if the **RDS** instance are running, and if they are, to stop them, look like. 
And if they are not running, the script should exit with a message:

> No instances running.

I have used **aws cli** to start and stop the instances, but I am not sure how to collaborate them in one single script.

```
aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance
```

Comment: You could simply issue the command, because stopping an already-stopped instance doesn't really cause a problem. Alternatively, you could use `aws rds describe-db-instances` to discover the current status. Please show us the script you have tried so far, and what difficulties you have encountered (eg error messages).

Comment: If your RDS have any read replica then the STOP option will never work.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the cli command as per the aws documentation: 
aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance

Does not work as expected.
Am I not doing it right?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Any suggestion on how could I check if my RDS have read replicas?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?